# Executing a java MVC project using .bat files

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, model-view-controller, rmi

I have a fully working java project that runs an RMI API. It includes 3 Main-classes that i'm supose to run thorugh 3 separate .bat files.

[image: Package explorer:]

The classes that I need to run are (in that order): Model_Server, Controller_Server, View_Server.

I have 2 version of batch code that iv'e tried. Problem is, that in both of them, even though i duplicated the batch code to all 3 classes (excluding class and package names of course), only the first class (Model_Server) actually works as in Eclipse.

First version is:

```
@cd %cd%\src
@for /r %%a in (*.java) do @javac %%a
@start rmiregistry 3000
@java Model.Model_Server
```

Running Model_Server.bat looks like this:
[image: Model_Server batch run using second version]

Running Controller_Server.bat looks like this:
[image: Controller_Server batch run using second version]

The second version of code is this:

```
cd src\
javac *.java
java Controller.Controller_Server
pause
```

But the results are the same - Model_Server gives the proper result but the 2 other calsses don't.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is something wrong with the `javac` commands, but you should just get rid of all the `javac` stuff. Your IDE should do that.

Comment: Got rid of the 'javac' commands but still...only .bat file that's working is the first one. The others do not but i have no idea why is that.

Comment: Neither does anybody else until you update your question with the current output, **as text** as requested.